Primes of the form $3^a+2^b$ or $3^a-2^b$
I was searching for information about prime numbers, and somehow, I ended up verifying whether certain numbers are prime. I seem to have stumbled upon some far-fetched relationships with the following formulas that express prime numbers. Do these equations originate from a particular theorem? I would like to know, although it’s more likely just a coincidence.
Some primes: 
$3^0+2$ 
$3^1+2$ 
$3^2+2,\  3^2-2$ 
$3^3+2$ 
$3^4-2,\  3^2+2$ 
$3^5-2$, 
$3^6-2,\  3^6+2^2$ 
$3^7-2^3,\  3^7+2^4$ 
$3^8-2^5$ 
$3^9-2,\  3^9+2^2,\  3^9+2^4,\  3^9-2^8$ 
$3^{10}+2$

I'm unclear on what relationship you're seeing. It's true that $3^a \pm 2^b$ is sometimes prime, but it's not evident what you want to claim beyond this.

Are you claiming that for every $m$ there is an $n<m$ such that at least one of $3^m\pm2^n$ is prime?

The exponents must be coprime or $0$. But a sufficient condition would be the greatest theorem for many centuries.

You wrote $3^2+2$ twice

The exponents need not be coprime or $0$ , $2^4+3^4$ is a prime with equal exponents.

The primes of this form exhibit no particular pattern , we can expect infinite many primes of this form , but I am pretty sure that it is open whether we actually have infinite many of them. There is no hope to classify the primes of this form.

This is not an answer but a long comment on experimental observations and elaboration the comment by @Gerry Myerson, "Are you claiming that for every $$ there is an $<$ such that at least one of $3^ \pm 2^$ is prime?"
This claim is false but the counter examples are few. $m = 103, 117, 170, 178, 204, 333, 586, 736, 752$ and $980$ are the only value of $m$ for which there is no solution.
The data however, showed a curious pattern in the growth rate of the number of such solutions. Let $f(m)$ be the numbers of integers $n$ such that $3^m + 2^n$ is a prime and let $g(m)$ be the numbers of integers $n$ such that $3^m - 2^n$ is a prime. Then there are constants $A \approx 2.55$ and $B \approx 2.20$ such that
$$
\sum_{m \le x}f(m) \sim Ax, \text{ and} \sum_{m \le x}g(m) \sim Bx,
$$

